# Attach an action helper function to Embers link-to

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to figure out how to attach a function to an ember `{{link-to}}` object.

The function is supposed to update a number in the progress bar indicating to user where they are in the process. Is there a way to look at the url and update the number using the router and the switch statement, or is the way I am approaching it now a good start? not really seeing any examples out there..

html

```
<nav class="progress">
  {{link-to "Next" "checkout.setup" action="updateStepNumber"}}
  {{link-to "Next" "checkout.upload" action="updateStepNumber"}}
  {{link-to "Next" "checkout.gather" action="updateStepNumber"}}
  {{link-to "Next" "checkout.watch" action="updateStepNumber"}}
  {{link-to "Next" "checkout.review" action="updateStepNumber"}}
</nav>
<div>
  <span class="step-number> 1 </span> of <span>5</span>
</div>
```

JS

```
App.CheckoutReviewController = Ember.Controller.extend(Ember.Evented, {
  needs: ['checkout', 'helpers', 'application'],

 updateStepNumber: function(){
    var stepNumber = $('.step-number');
    stepNumber ++
    stepNumber.append(stepNumber)
    }
```

Comment: Why not update it from the route in the activate hook?

Comment: not sure, sounds like a  good idea though can you provide an example please?

Comment: Mind setting up a [jsBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/) with what you have at the moment?